# How do I make the vertical divider equal and start at same top with variable content in CSS

Tags: html, css

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/7x0kej46/3/

```
<section>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehender
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
   <div>
  TEST
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>

section div {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

section div::after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
  width: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

section div:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Desired Output (added a better picture for understanding)

[image]

Comment: You see the vertical line over the left ?? For fixed height div's , the line can be made to start and end at same points, by hardcoding the height, top, and left properties. But when the div content is not fixed due to content vary then its difficult, you get my point. ?

Comment: Pretty sure you're gonna need JS for this to determine the height of the following div.

Comment: Actually, you *might* be able to use **two** pseudo elements that meet at the right point...one on the previous div and one on the following. I'd have to think.

Comment: So you want the lines to start at the middle of the first element, and have them reaching into the next element by a _specific_ amount of pixels (or rem, or something like that)? Then remove the `height`, and specify `bottom: -2rem` or something like that.

Comment: (And next time, please use your _words_, to explain _exactly_ what you want, instead of just pointing a pictures.)

Comment: Well i really cant post the original UI that I am working on as i do not have permissions to put it :) so you can imagine my situation how to explain

Comment: i have added a better picture this time. Hope it helps, so this time we have icons so the divider has to start and stop with variable length content

Comment: This _still_ doesn’t answer what I asked you. _“Well i really cant post the original UI that I am working on as i do not have permissions to put it”_ - I already asked you to please use your _words_ to explain what exactly you need, so why are you showing yet another picture anyway?

Comment: Assuming(!) you want the circles to start a fixed distance from the top of the element, and have the lines reach into the next element by a fixed length as well, I would go with something like this then, https://jsfiddle.net/k5mcojvg/

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo elements that meet at the right point...one on the previous div and one on the following.

```css
section div {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

section div::after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 5px solid #555;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  height: calc(50% + .5em);
}

section div::before {
  content: '';
  border-right: 5px solid #555;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  height: calc(50% + .5em);
  bottom: 50%;
}

section div:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

section div:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehender
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div>
    TEST
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good base to start from according to your design:

```css
section div {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3rem;
}

section div::after {
  content: '';
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
  width: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 35px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}


section div::before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 11px;
}

section div:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehender
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
   <div>
  TEST
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn one line using pseudo element of section then put icon using child div pseudo element.

Hope this may help you.

```css
section{
  position:relative;
}
section:before{
  content:"";
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:15px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:1;
}

section div {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
section div:before {
   content:"-";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:1px;
  top:15%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:100%;
  z-index:3;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-size: 28px;
   line-height: 16px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
      transform: rotate(-50deg);
      background-color:red;
      color:#fff;
}
section div:nth-child(2):before {
  content:"✔";
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:20px;
  background-color:green;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
}

section div:first-child:after,section div:last-child:after {
  content:"";
  width:2px;
  height:15%;
  position:absolute;
  left:15px;
  top:0;
  background-color:#ccc;
  z-index:2;
}
section div:last-child:after {
  top:auto;
  bottom:0;
  height:85%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehender
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
   <div>
  TEST
  </div>
   <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```